# Como fazer uma busca no MYSQL considerando plural e singular

Tags: mysql, select, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho um site de receitas com um sistema de busca simples. Mas tem receitas que estão no plural e receitas no singular, por exemplo:

biscoito de chocolate e biscoitos de chocolate

Quando alguém procura por biscoito de chocolate, o select busca só o que é biscoito de chocolate, tem alguma forma de eu fazer para ele trambém trazer o biscoitos de chocolate? (no plural)

Meu select está assim:

```
SELECT titulo, foto
FROM receitas
WHERE (titulo LIKE '%{$_GET['termo']}%' OR descricao LIKE '%{$_GET['termo']}%')
```

E a busca é um input simples:

```
<form method="get">
  <input name="termo">
</form>
```

Comment: Divide o termo por palavra (ex: delimitador " ") e remove os últimos dois caracteres de cada palavra do termo, porque nem sempre o plurar é um s.

Comment: então, mas daí no caso de biscoitos de chocolate não vai adiantar, pq o que está no plural é o biscoito

Comment: Vou editar a resposta em cima para ficar mais simples

Answer (score 1):

Opa, bem vamos lá.

A forma que eu faria é um pouquinho trabalhosa, mas em teoria daria certo, mas você teria que estruturar um pouquinho melhor com o PHP.

Eu começaria tratando o termo que foi digitado pelo usuário, retirando alguns caracteres do final (ai varia do que você precisa, 2,3,4 caracteres...)

```
//Exemplo iniciando no caracter 0 e retirando o 1 CHAR da string (final do termo):
$filtro = substr($_GET['termo'], 0, 1);
```

Claro que o exemplo acima, você teria que melhorar um pouco separando as palavras também pelos espaços (estimo que os usuários do seu site pesquisem por BISCOITO DE CHOCOLATE, então nesse caso seria 3 variáveis ao menos para separar os termos, e depois você poderia concatenar numa variavel as strings já tratadas e utilizar ela como parâmetro de busca no seu SQL.

Após ajustar, você iniciaria a consulta

```
-- Buscando por elementos que contenham a palavra dentro da variavel $filtro
SELECT titulo, foto
FROM receitas
WHERE (titulo LIKE '%$filtro%' OR descricao LIKE '%$filtro%')
```

Ou se você preferir, pode pesquisar por termos que contenham palavras que comecem com um caracter específico

```
-- Buscando dados que comecem com qualquer caracter e finalizem com o $filtro
    SELECT titulo, foto
    FROM receitas
    WHERE (titulo LIKE '_$filtro%' OR descricao LIKE '_$filtro%')
```

Ou ainda, verificar se o termo INICIAL da pesquisa contem os caracteres filtrados e qualquer outro caracters aleatório que possa a vir existir no seu banco:

```
-- Buscando dados que comecem com $filtro e terminam com qualquer caracter
        SELECT titulo, foto
        FROM receitas
        WHERE (titulo LIKE '$filtro_' OR descricao LIKE '$filtro_')
```

Creio que a opção 3 seja a mais viável pro seu caso, mas caso ainda não seja o que precisa, você pode dar uma consultada nestes materiais que usei como base:
Fonte: https://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-os-operadores-like-in-e-between-no-oracle/24687
Fonte: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php

Algo importante que você pode fazer é o seguinte. Caso o usuário tenha digitado 3 ou + palavras, fazer a busca no seu SQL com mais parâmetros passando todas as strings possíveis para refinar a busca com todas as palavras contidas no termo.

Espero ajudar, compartilhe conosco o resultado!

Answer (score 1):

O ideal nesse caso é utilizar o método de pesquisa FULLTEXT ao invés de LIKE.

Vala ressaltar que isso não vai buscar as palavras quebradas, ou seja, ele continua fazendo a busca por palavras porem o que vai definir se vai ser exibido ou não o resultado é o conjunto, a frase no caso.
No exemplo que você utilizou, como os dois registros contem a palavra 'chocolate' eles serão exibidos, indiferente de biscoito estar no singular ou no plural.

Para utilizar esse recurso você precisa fazer alterações na estrutura do banco de dados e adicionar os índices fulltext nas colunas que você quer realizar a busca, nada muito complicado. Vou te passar um exemplo.

Vou criar uma tabela apenas para testar o resultado:
Note que já criei os índices fulltext nas colunas em que desejo realizar pesquisas

```
CREATE TABLE receitas
(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    titulo VARCHAR(200),
    corpo TEXT,
    FULLTEXT (titulo, corpo)

);
```

Agora vou adicionar uns campos no singular e plural parecidos:

```
INSERT INTO receitas (`titulo`, `corpo`) VALUES ('biscoito de chocolate', 'descricao da receita');
INSERT INTO receitas (`titulo`, `corpo`) VALUES ('biscoitos de chocolate', 'descricao da receita');
INSERT INTO receitas (`titulo`, `corpo`) VALUES ('cookies de chocolate', 'descricao da receita');
INSERT INTO receitas (`titulo`, `corpo`) VALUES ('cookie de banana', 'descricao da receita');
```

Query de pesquisa. Coloquei uma variável para simular a sua:

```
set @pesquisa := 'biscoito de chocolate';

SELECT titulo, corpo FROM receitas 
    WHERE MATCH(titulo) AGAINST (@pesquisa in natural language mode);
```

Essa busca vai retornar os dois biscoitos, tanto no singular como no plural, mas também vai retornar o 'cookies de chocolate'.
O MATCH retornar um calculo de relevância da sua busca, que é muito legal para você ordenar os resultados por exemplo. Vou passar um exemplo ilustrativo só para você entender como funciona:

```
SELECT titulo, corpo,  MATCH(titulo, corpo) AGAINST (@pesquisa in natural language mode) AS score
FROM receitas
    WHERE MATCH(titulo) AGAINST (@pesquisa in natural language mode)
        ORDER BY score DESC;
```

Mas o mais interessante mesmo é quando for criar tabelas deste tipo já criar uma coluna com palavras chaves, que o usuário preenche ao inserir o registro no banco de dados, assim colocaria no as palavras no singular no plural e adicionaria qualquer keyword que for relevante para a pesquisa. Depois é só você direcionar a busca para essa coluna de keywords. Isso criaria um sistema de busca muito mais poderoso para o seu sistema.